# Why the logic of UnobservedTaskException was changed in .net 4.5?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, unobserved-exception

As we [know](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.taskscheduler.unobservedtaskexception(v=vs.110).aspx) in .net 4.5 UnobservedTaskException does not crash an app.

> To make it easier for developers to write asynchronous code based on
>   tasks, the .NET Framework 4.5 changes the default exception behavior
>   for unobserved exceptions. Although unobserved exceptions still raise
>   the UnobservedTaskException exception, the process does not terminate
>   by default. Instead, the exception is handled by the runtime after the
>   event is raised, regardless of whether an event handler observes the
>   exception. This behavior can be configured. Starting with the .NET
>   Framework 4.5, you can use the configuration element to revert to the
>   behavior of the .NET Framework 4 and terminate the process:

Ok, assume Microsoft decided to change the experience of multi-thread working with exceptions but why it applied only for tpl then?
Why the other parts of multi-thread mechanisms was not changed?
Eg, the following code still crash the app

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(state => { throw new Exception(); });
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

It's confusing and looks very strange.
Anybody know anything about this?

Comment: "Why the other parts ... was not changed?" is easy, that would promote bad software. Why the regime for Tasks was lightened is a good question though.

Comment: Agree. But I don't understand why Task logic has been changed. We was able to use TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException event to hide and log exceptions if we want...

Comment: `TaskScheduler.UnobservedTaskException` offers a false sense of security to begin with, since faulted tasks only raise this event if and when they are finalized. It's quite easy for a task to never get finalized (or only at a time when handling the error is no longer interesting), so it's not even guaranteed that a faulted task can actually be observed. At least not crashing has the benefit of being consistent, in that you're guaranteed that *no* unobserved fault will bother you. :-P

Comment: The TPL is a mechanism to handle async computation but it is NOT connected directly to Threads / ThreadPools etc.., it's an abstraction atop of it to make dev easier - if you choose to use the more primitive objects you should know what your doing...

Comment: @barakcaf, have you read a question? I don't understand why you posted your comment :)

Comment: you ask why microsoft changed only the tpl mechanism, well i've suggested a possible reason...

Comment: Because there's absolutely no reason you should have to observe the result of a task. In many cases, you simply can't. Forcing people to observe complete tasks, would force them to do things like... stores tasks in a list and then monitor the list for completed tasks. That's totally incompatible with a fire-and-forget kind of asynchronous operation. You don't need to necessarily do or handle the completion of an asynchronous operation.

Comment: For example, I have a WinForms Control that receives an Operation object that has a Task property representing completion of a data load.  When the control is assigned the Operation, it attaches to the Task with a call to ContinueWith on that Task to render the data when the load completes, but that ContinueWith also returns a Task! I don't need that last Task. It becomes a chicken and egg problem. I'd need a task (or thread) to 'wait' on the Task returned by ContinueWith to complete in order to observe it. That's useless. The continuation is all I need, and then it's done.

Comment: I mean... I guess instead of calling ContinueWith, I could just call Task.GetAwaiter().OnComplete(Action), which doesn't return a Task. :/